# Multiple Errors in Uploading Database Columns MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am new to MySQL and am uploading a database for the first time. I am not uploading the data, just the columns for now. The issue is that I get an error for every line of code provided:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

I can understand if I was getting the message for just one or two lines of the code, but I am beginning to think I misformatted all the database file since I'm getting that error message for every line.

I previously changed the primary/foreign keys

```
CONSTRAINT `PurchasePK` PRIMARY KEY (`P_ORDERNO`)
CONSTRAINT `PurchaseFK` FOREIGN KEY (`SUPPLY_CODE`)
```

to:   `P_ORDERNO` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,

And still get errors.

I would appreciate if someone took a look at the contents of the .sql file below and let me know if there is something I am missing that is giving me consistent errors.

```
-- Table structure for table `Purchase`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Purchase` (
  `P_ORDERNO` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  `SUPPLY_CODE` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment FOREIGN KEY,
  `P_ORDER_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `P_ORDER_AMT` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `SUPPLY_DESC` varchar(50) NULL,
  `SUPPLY QTY` int(5) NOT NULL,
);
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- Table structure for table `Vendor`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Vendor` (
  `VENDORNO` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  `VENDOR_NAME` varchar(50) NULL,
  `VENDOR_STREET` varchar(50) NULL,
  `VENDOR_CITY` varchar(50) NULL,
  `VENDOR_STATE` varchar(2) NULL,
  `VENDOR_ZIP` varchar(3) NULL,
  `VENDOR_AREA_CODE` varchar(5) NULL,
  `VENDOR_PHONE` varchar(10) NULL,
);
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- Table structure for table `Supply`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Supply` (
  `SUPPLY_CODE` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  `SUPPLY_DESC` varchar(50) NULL,
  `SUPPLY QTY` int(5) NOT NULL,
);
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have trailing commas

```
  `SUPPLY QTY` int(5) NOT NULL,
                              ^---here
);
```

in each of the table definitions. That makes the DB server expect another field definition, but instead it runs into `);`